# High CPU-Memory usage by Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, cpu-usage

I have an EC2 instance running Postgresql-13 with one database that isn't large i think

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('postgres')) -> 136 MB
```

I inserted about 500k rows yesterday and now i've a very high usage on cpu and memory due to autovacuume as the processes shows.

- I tried to kill the process but it still shows again
- I changed the autovacuum property to off in the config and still appears (i know that is bad practice but I was testing).

Any idea if that's normal or if there is a solution.

[image: top command]

[image: Postgres grep]

Comment: You've probably been hacked and are running a crypto miner program which is trying to disguise itself as a autovacuum worker.  I don't see any reason `top` would report a real worker as being 'memory', nor is 'autovacuum reader' how the real process would describe itself.

Comment: @jjanes so how to confirm if that's true or not on the server?

Comment: If you can find the 'memory' binary, you could upload it to virustotal and see what it says about it.  It should be owned by OS user 'postgres'.  You could look in the postgresql log file to see if it reports a bunch of login attempts, as they worked their way through the password guessing exercise.

Comment: @jjanes i listed the postgres directory on the system and it shows the following https://i.imgur.com/zCqvUhN.png is this normal or that what you are talking about? and how to deal with that

Comment: The ones in green (memroy, pg_mem, and prememory) none of them belong there.  That is nearly conclusive evidence that you have been hacked.

Comment: @jjanes well thats a good step, now should i only delete and then move on with the security issue with our postgres, or there are steps needed to delete these files and clean the server

Comment: The safest is to burn it down and start over.  You never know what all  they did when they had access.  Pragmatically, you should at least fix the access method (almost surely a guessed weak password on the DB superuser account) and reboot first, otherwise they will just keep coming back and dropping new exploit files.

Comment: @jjanes I manage to download the memory file and scanned it and virustotal says it's malicious unfortunately, and i found that it duplicated it self in more than one folder in the system so i think i agree that terminate the instance and configure another is the safest way to go